# Should we use all pluralized URI in a RESTful or differentiate between uses

Tags: rest, uri, url-design

I have seen quite bit of different answers on how people use the URIs in REST. I tend to use plurals for collections and singulars for single ressource. But it requires more routing.

Is it ok to use plurals for all ressources? For example:

```
GET /ressources               // to all ressources
GET /ressources/{id}          // to get one ressource
DELETE /ressources/{id}       // to delete one ressource
```

or should I stick with:

```
GET /ressources
GET /ressource/{id}           
DELETE /ressource/{id}
```

Is it valid in all cases?
What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score -1):

I use pluralized URI as you outlined